# Remove session value on page change, close, or refresh the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, webforms

I need to clear session value when user navigate to some other page, refresh or close browser. I had tried onunload event of asp.net but its not helpfull.

Or Is it possible to set session value in JavaScript? as session store at server side so I think we can not access session in JavaScript.

Comment: you could access to your session value in javascript by AJAX request, btw your question seem to broad

Comment: Don't use `Session`. Use `hiddenfield` or `viewstate` or `querystring`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try remove/set the session before the initial load of the page:

```
.. Page_Load() {
 if( !IsPostBack ) {
 Session.Remove("key"); // or Abandon(), or Clear().
}
}
```